# Find a string and replace another string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a text file which contains the follwing

```
{"sno":"1c8d1d7eaa32ff3f58a8822111276d5a","at":"app","tt":{"AppParam1":"AppParamValue1","AppParam2":"AppParamValue2"}},"c":{"dt":"Microsoft XDeviceEmulator","pn":"WP","pv":"8.0.9832.0"}
```

In java I want to find 'sno', 'pn' and 'pv' and replace the values of (what I mean is) currently the above text file has

```
"sno" has value "1c8d1d7eaa32ff3f58a8822111276d5a"
"pn" has value "WP"
"pv" has value "8.0.9832.0"
```

New values

```
"sno" has to be changed to "637829"
"pn"  has to be changed to "XYZ"
"pv" has to be changed to "2.2.4.0"
```

Your help is much appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  As an aside - what is your question?

Comment: That looks like a JSON. Why don't you try a JSON library rather than inventing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it into JSON, make you changes and then convert it back to string.
Or if you really want to replace these values by yourself, you can use these lines :

```
yourstring = yourstring.replaceFirst("\"sno\":\"[^\"]+\"", "\"sno\":\"637829\"");
yourstring = yourstring.replaceFirst("\"pn\":\"[^\"]+\"", "\"pn\":\"XYZ\"");
yourstring = yourstring.replaceFirst("\"pv\":\"[^\"]+\"", "\"pv\":\"2.2.4.0\"");
```

Only if there are no way theses key can be found elsewhere in the string

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON object.

Convert that string to a JSON object, change the values and then convert it again to a string.

Here you can read about JSON objects in java: http://www.json.org/java/

And here an easy tuto on how to work with them: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Comment: Yes, you are right, its a json. But I m treating it as a normal String value and want to replace the values of the key adhoc